# Google Loader doesn't work anymore

Tags: google-api, google-loader

I'm trying to retrieve current user location by Google Loader. But I don't know why it stopped work. Any time the page is loaded, google.loader.ClientLocation is null and can't get any location. My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=MY_APP_KEY"></script>
```

And then the javascript code:

```
    google.load("search", "1", {callback: initialize});

    function initialize() {

        if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
            var userCountry = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country;
            var userLocation = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.city;
            var userRegion = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.region;
            var userCountryCode = google.loader.ClientLocation.address.country_code;

            $.ajax({
                url: "${createLink(controller: 'util', action: 'userLocation')}",
                data: { city: userLocation, region: userRegion, country: userCountry, countryCode: userCountryCode }
            })
                    .done(function(data) {
                        $("#userLocation").html(userLocation + ", " + userRegion + " - " + userCountry +
                                ' <img src="' + data + '"/>'
                        );
                    });
        }

    }
```

Thanks!